# Ban command discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

this is my first topic here, well, I am creating a ban command for my bot in discord.js, and I would like to know how I would do it so that if I don't specify a reason, it will add "unspecified reason" and continue to ban the user for no reason!

below I will leave my code for you to have a base, if possible assemble for me thank you!

```
var testCont = message.content.split(" ");
    var content = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(' ');
    var banned = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (message.mentions.users.size < 1) {
        message.reply("Você deve fornecer um usuário para eu banir!");
    } 
    else if (testCont.length <= 2) {
        message.reply("Por favor, forneça o motivo do banimento.");
    } 
    else if (message.guild.member(banned).bannable) {

      client.users.cache.get(banned.id).send({
        embed: {
            color: (client.config.discord.EMBED_COLOR),
            description: `<:emoji_17:835279180992217140>︙Você foi banido de **${message.guild.name}**\n<:emoji_30:835278700206882846>︙**Motivo:**\n \`\`\`diff\n- ${content}\`\`\`\n<:emoji_30:835278700206882846>︙**Banido por:** ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `content` is the reason for the ban in your case, just see if they provided `content`, if not update `content`.Eg:

```
if(!content){ //checks if the reason is provided or not.
    content = "No reason provided.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value of content is '' and then give it a new value.

```js
if (content === '')
{
    content = "No reason specified";
}
```